# Wine mount folder as drive

Tags: ubuntu, directory, mount, wine

I have dropbox installed across several computers, on windows I can mount the Dropbox as a virtual folder (in my case M:\). I want to do the same on wine on Ubuntu so that I can use the same project files across multiple computers and have all the file paths work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Never mind, I found the answer, it's actually quite easy, just go into the .wine folder in the home directory (you may need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to show the hidden folders) and then into the `dosdevices` folder. You can then just create a shortcut (`ln -s TARGET LINK`) to the folder you want to appear as a drive and name it letter-colon
i.e. `m:`